# How to use jquery keyup on multiple input fields?

Tags: jquery, keyup

I'm trying to output the values of multiple input-fields into a single div.
But I simply can't get it to work. It will only output one of the input-fields into the div at a time.

This is my jquery:

```
var $output = $('#output-content-here');
  $('input').keypress( function() {
  $($output).text(this.value);
});
```

I have made a jsiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/1/

Thanks.

Comment: A general piece of advice: Never double wrap a jQuery object (as in `$($output)`, $output already being a jQuery object). It accomplishes nothing, but adds run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code using **[`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**

```
var $output = $('#output-content-here');

$('input').keyup(function () {
    $output.html(function () {
        return $('input').map(function () {
            return this.value
        }).get();
    })
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/11/)**

**Note** : `$output` already contains jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var $output = $('#output-content-here');

$('input').keyup( function() {
    $output.html($('input').map(function(){
        return this.value + ((this.value.length)?"<br>":"");
    }).get().join(''));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/A7UbK/10/)

Comment: +1 although it should be using `keyup`, not `keypress`, otherwise the character from the current event is not shown: http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/7/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah was updating it.. Anyway thanks for the encouragement..!

Answer (score 0):

As other answers display, you can `map` the values each time into the `div` element.

Personally I think a tidier method would be to have 3 elements nested inside the `div`, 1 for each input, and apply the value directly to each relevant element.

This means you're only updating the field which has been edited, not the entire `div` html.

```
Name<input id="name" type="text" name="name" /> <br />
Besked<input id="message" type="text" name="message" /> <br /> 
Number<input id="number" type="text" name="number" /> <br /> 

<div id="output-content-here">
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="message"></span>
    <span class="number"></span>
</div>

var $output = $('#output-content-here');

$('input').keyup( function() {    
    $output.find("." + this.id).text(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A7UbK/13/